# Laravel. Eloquent query for two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to write laravel eloquent query which could select all the titles from titles table where title_id doesnt't exist in title_count table. Here is an example. 
titles table:

```
title_id
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

title_count table:

```
title_id 
    3
    4
```

So my query should select titles with id's 1, 2 from title table. To be honest, I have no ideo how to do it. I'm using laravel 5.
 I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for collection function (since Eloquent returns Collection object); http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_diff  `$titles->all()->diff($title_count->all());` code should look like. I am not sure and I am not going to test it right now.

Comment: You were right. Collection function is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: If you solve problem make an answer, or delete your question; good luck Artisan.

Comment: Filtering all results via the Collection object is inefficient.  Instead, use SQL to pull only the titles that do not have counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join to to identify titles that do not appear in title_count.

```
DB::table('titles')->leftJoin('title_count', 'titles.title_id', '=', 'title_count.title_id')
                   ->select('titles.*')
                   ->whereNull('title_count.title_id')
                   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DB::table('titles')->whereNotExists(function($query)
{
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
       ->from('title_count')
       ->whereRaw('title_count.title_id = titles.title_id');
})->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Not tested

```
DB::table('title_count')
  ->leftJoin('titles as t', 't.title_id', '=', 'title_count.title_id')
  ->select('t.*')
  ->where('t.title_id', '!=', 'title_count.title_id')
  ->get();
```